# android activity not showing in only main activity and not showing properly

Tags: java, android, mobile

action bar not showing in main activity while the same code present for another activity and another thing action bar overflow not showing by list in right corner

1. image 1 : main activity with menu key pressed

[image]

2. image 2 : show message activity

[image]

code for main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText t;
public final static String sendMessageextra="com.example.example2.textmessage";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.textmessage);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public void sendMessage(View v){
    Intent sendmessageintent=new Intent(this,showMessage.class);
    String messagestring=t.getText().toString();
    sendmessageintent.putExtra(sendMessageextra, messagestring);
    startActivity(sendmessageintent);
}
```

}

show message activity:

```
public class showMessage extends Activity{
TextView t;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sendmessage);
    t=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.showmessage);
    showmessage();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
    return true;
}


public void showmessage(){
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String message=intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.sendMessageextra);
    t.setText(message);
    Log.i("Set New Text Box", "Text BOx");
}
```

}

activity main actions.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search Widget -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

<!-- Location Found -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
      android:title="@string/action_location_found"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
<!-- Help -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
      android:title="@string/action_help" 
      android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

android menifest file:
Activity Manifest File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.example2.showMessage"
            android:label="Show Message" android:parentActivityName="com.example.example2.MainActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Which is your launcher activity in manifest file??

Comment: added Android manifest file .... please help me fast #Rohit

Comment: FAST? what does this mean?

Comment: FAST means i'm in hurry ....

Comment: I have posted answer please mention in comments below answers if you are facing any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the search icon in the right of the actionbar in every activity then just make a change in the actions.xml instead of android:showAsAction="ifRoom" change it to android:showAsAction="always"

Answer (score 0):

1. `ActionBar` not showing

Do this in your oncreate()

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.show();
```

2. `ActionBar overflow` 
   there you can see your menu

To display menu, In your activity main actions.xml,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

Like this you need to do changes in main actions file

Comment: wt about overflow ??
that should have to shown as a list at top right corner but it is showing on bottom even on android 4.1

Comment: you will see three dots (:) like this. From there only you can see your menu